# how to swtich between parentheses inside a string with php

Tags: php, regex

I have string for example ")bla bla(" and I would like to switch between the parentheses with php regex so the output will be "(bla bla)"

Comment: What prevents you from simply replacing them with each other?

Comment: What about string for example `))(bla)(` ?

Comment: Good question @revo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all kinds of ways to do that, here is just one...

```
<?php

$string = 'I have string for example ")bla bla(" and I would like to switch between the parentheses with php regex so the output will be "(bla bla)"';

echo preg_replace ( '/\)(.*?)\(/', '($1)', $string );

?>
```